# DISTINCT ON in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

How would I do the following query:

```
OrderNotes.objects.filter(item=item).distinct('shared_note')
```

Basically, I need to get all `OrderNotes` items, distinct on `shared_note`. When I try and do this I get:

```
    raise NotImplementedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')

NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

I am using mysql and cannot change the db here. What would be the workaround in django?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
OrderNotes.objects.filter(item=item).values_list('shared_note', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: What if you wish to have the full objects and not only the unique values ? :-) Getting a bit stuck ...

Answer (score 8):

This is the best I came up with:

```
>>> items, item_ids = [], []
>>> for item in OrderNotes.objects.filter(shared_note=219):
...     if item.shared_note not in item_ids:
...         items.append(item)
...         item_ids.append(item.shared_note)
```