# Catching a NotImplemented error during a distinct call in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-queryset

Ok. So [SQLLite can't make distinct calls in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626175/distinct-on-in-django). *Fine.* I'm ok with that.

So I'm trying to build an app that can be deployed anywhere, mostly Postgres, but occasionally on other platforms and want a method to always return a queryset.

So I have code like this:

```
try:
    states = qs.distinct('registrationAuthority')
except: # (NotImplementedError, e):
    print(e)
    print(e.message)
    if e.message == "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend":
        current = []
        seen_ras = []
        for s in states:
            ra = s.registrationAuthority
            if ra not in seen_ras:
                current.append(s.pk)
                seen_ras.append(ra)
        # We hit again so we can return this as a queryset
        states = states.filter(pk__in=current_ids)
    else:
        raise
return states
```

Except on a non-`DISTINCT` supporting database, the catch *never* catches. I just get this traceback:

```
>>> p.current_statuses()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 162, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 829, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 393, in as_sql
    result.append(self.connection.ops.distinct_sql(distinct_fields))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py", line 132, in distinct_sql
    raise NotImplementedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

How can I properly catch a `NotImplementedError` in a chained queryset call like this?

Comment: Querysets are evaluated lazily. Maybe the Exception is raised outside the try-except block?

Comment: Why not catch NotImplementedError then ' "distinct" in str(e).lower() '?

Comment: @HåkenLid You handsome genius!! That was it! Make it an answer!

Comment: I've made it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querysets are evaluated lazily. Maybe the Exception is raised outside the try-except block?

You can force evaluation inside the `try except` in [various ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

```
try:
    _states = qs.distinct('registrationAuthority')
    bool(_states)  # evaluate queryset
    states = _states
except NotImplementedError:
    # do something to make a clean states variable here
```

Of note is that this won't work:

```
try:
    states = qs.distinct('registrationAuthority')
    bool(states)  # evaluate queryset
except NotImplementedError:
    states = states.filter() # error raised here
```

As in the exception block, `states` will still have the distinct filter chained on the end, as it wasn't *stripped* when the exception was caught.

Comment: I added a bit of a clarification that I found when implementing this, but you made it much, much easier!

Comment: Why don't you just use `qs.filter()` in the except block?

Comment: Because at that line `states` is still set to `qs.distinct` because that is the lazy-unevaluated value from the try block.

Comment: `states = qs` will remove the distinct. You can confirm that the original qs is not modified  by `assert 'DISTINCT' not in str(qs.query)`