# Django model filtering with distinct on a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I may have a simple Django filtering questing. I need a way to select only unique on a ForeignKey, like a distinct.

my models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ....

class Share(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    ....
```

I need a way to get all shares with only unique post.user's and need only to get the latest post, to make a inbox.

I ended up with something like ..

```
Share.objects.filter(user=request.user).distinct("post__user").order_by("post__created")
```

But i gets an error::
**DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend**

Is there a way to make this work?, and what is the best solution?

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: answer the question by @zsquare

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISTINCT ON in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626175/distinct-on-in-django)

Comment: i am using sqlite3 in my dev setup .. and postgres on my prod setup .. would a solution that works on both DB's ..

Comment: I need one share pr. unique user, this only gives my the unique user, but not the latest share pr. user ... Share.objects.filter(user__id=1).values_list('post__user', flat=True).distinct()