# Filter, then ordering and get distinct on queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a list of agents, i want to filter this list then ordering it by comments they wrote (if agent wrote a comment then he should appear at the top of my list). The problem is i getting 3 times the same agents in my list because he wrote 3 comments.

I tried to add distinct to the end of the query but i got this error :
`NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

Here my query that produce x agents if one agent wrote x comments

```
agents = Agent.objects.filter(name__icontains=name, metier__name__icontains=metier,
                                          code_uf__icontains=code_uf, grade_code__icontains=grade,
                                          matricule__icontains=matricule).order_by('-comments')
```

Here the query with distinct :

```
agents = Agent.objects.filter(name__icontains=name, metier__name__icontains=metier,
                                          code_uf__icontains=code_uf, grade_code__icontains=grade,
                                          matricule__icontains=matricule).order_by('-comments').distinct('comments')
```

I expected to get my list agents with no duplicates agents. The list type should be queryset (because i'm using all param after). For moment i got 3 times the same agent in my list because he wrotes 3 comments...

Comment: What if you replace `distinct(...)` by `aggregate(Count('comments'))`?

Comment: Hello, thank for your comment. If i replace by aggregate i lose my list of agents and i get 'comments__count' instead. I need as output a list of agent without duplicates

Comment: Yeah my bad, that was a mistake. Take a look there, it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626175/distinct-on-in-django

Comment: i would like the full object. If there is no answer i will do it as the author did in his answer. But i hope there is something cleaner :)

Comment: If you are stuck, keep in mind you still can use an SQL query (`Agent.objects.raw('SELECT name, metier... FROM prj_c GROUP BY name, metier...')`)

Comment: yes thank i'll think about it if nobody answer it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after more research i found the solution. I have used [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate), then `order_by` on this `annotate`.

```
agents = Agent.objects.filter(name__icontains=name, metier__name__icontains=metier,
                                          code_uf__icontains=code_uf, grade_code__icontains=grade,
                                          matricule__icontains=matricule).annotate(temp_date=Max("comments__date_created")).order_by("-temp_date")
```